# Changing the basis of a matrix of the linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$ be the matrix of the linear mapping $F: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual bases of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Find the matrix $B$ of the mapping $F$ in the bases $(1,2,3,4),(1,2,4,7),(0,1,1,1),(0,1,1,2)$ and $(1,3),(2,5)$.

I have done similar change of basis for $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, but never for $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$.  The relation that I discovered earlier, $B=C^{-1}AC$, no longer works since the dimensions no longer match.

EDIT: The only thought that I have is that I need to solve $$B  =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 5 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\ 4 & 7 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$